# How to profile the fetch time of the android gradle libraries

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have profiled gradle build using --profile flag. Following is the report spit by gradle.[image]

Actually in this report, it shows the total build time but doesn't say anything specifically about how much time it took to fetch libraries from the server. I would like to know that.

Is there any way I can get that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know how long it took to fetch libraries from the server, I guess the "Dependency Resolution" tab in the profile report is what to look for. If you want a more insights, you may want to try a [Gradle build scan](https://scans.gradle.com/get-started), which offers a detailed breakdown how long it took to download each dependency under [Performance -> Network Activity](https://docs.gradle.com/enterprise/get-started/#analyze_build_performance).
[image: Build scan download times]